# Mysql doesnt query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables like this.
I wanna make a query which is Select a Dvd only has Indian subtitle.

```
  CREATE TABLE dvd(
 `Id` INT NOT NULL,
 `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `Category` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Price` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));  

 CREATE TABLE Subtitles(
 `Id` INT NOT NULL,
 `Language` VARCHAR(45) NULL);
```

I'm trying to do this but this query selects every DVD has a Indian subtitles.

```
SELECT Name FROM DvD JOIN Subtitles 
ON  Dvd.Id=Subtitles.ID 
where Language='Indian' GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: There appears to be no relationship between the two tables

Answer (score 1):

The query doesn't work because the `where` clause is applied before the grouping. So you get all the rows where `Language='Indian'`, and then, every group has just one row.

One trick is to check that the maximum and minimum language are the same (meaning that there's just one row in the group), and that they are `Indian`. Note that the `where` clause should be removed:

```sql
SELECT   d.id
FROM     dvd d
JOIN     subtitles s ON  d.id = s.id
GROUP BY id
HAVING   MAX(language) = MIN(language) AND MAX(language) = 'Indian'
```

Comment: What does meaning of "MA"? you mean max maybe?

Comment: @marango1 yup, that was a typo. Thanks for noticing! Edited and fixed.

Comment: If I wanna select "name" instead of id, What should I do? When I edit SELECT   d.id with SELECT d.name it doesn't works. But It works like this : Select d.name, d.id